# Why is ProbabilityDistribution 100x slower than ExtremeValueDistribution?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, distributions

The two distributions are the same, except the ProbabilityDistribution cuts out below x=0. The wolfram documentation on ProbabilityDistribution says nothing about speed. A search of this site gave no obvious answer. Here is the code:

```
Dx = ExtremeValueDistribution[0.14068977685132567`, 
   0.10712657717044427`];
Dxp = ProbabilityDistribution[
   E^(-E^(((-x + 0.14068977685132567`)/0.10712657717044427`)) + (-x + 
     0.14068977685132567`)/0.10712657717044427`)/
   0.10712657717044427`, {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "Normalize"];
AbsoluteTiming[RandomVariate[Dx, 10^6];]
AbsoluteTiming[RandomVariate[Dxp, 10^6];]
```

Comment: Good question. I'd say that `ProbabilityDistribution` is a very general tool, so it needs a very general algorithm. I guess, when it is called with a generic function expression as firsts argument, it choses some rather general Monte-Carlo method. But if it detects one of the built-in distributions, such as `ExtremeValueDistribution` it can branch to a built-in algorithm that this tailored and optimized for this specific distribution. But maybe it is worth to report to Wolfram Research. Maybe they have overlooked some optimization potential in the generic branch...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just asked Wolfram tech support about it.

Comment: To generate random variates, the [`InverseCDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html) is needed.  For the distribution `Dx` this is easily obtained: `InverseCDF[Dx, q]`, For the distribution `Dxp` numeric techniques must be used.